# Java: could we lose DataInputStream when we manipulate it?

Tags: java

since I dont know how to generate DataInputStream easily, I cant test but pose my questions here. I use Java1.7

I need to manipulate an arrived DataInputStream, skip some bytes, call readShort() several times and skip another bytes. and I wonder:
Q1 if we will lose the original DataInputStream after the skip
Q2 after I call readShort(), would the stream move and point to the next position or it stays at the same position

Comment: How do you mean lose? If you skip the bytes you will not be able to read them again.  
If you call readShort you will move to the next position, since the short is read.

Comment: As soon as you read the input stream your mark is at the end or where you are reading in that moment. You need to reset in order to put back the position to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by 'generate DataInputStream', whether 'easily' or otherwise? What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I didnt get youre Question fully, but ill provide you 2 Examples, one for

> *readShort(), which reads two input bytes and returns a short value.*

and the

> *skipBytes(int n) method, which skips over n bytes of data from the*
>   *input stream. After skipping you will not be able to read them again*

### Now you are able to test freely

---

readShort()

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

public class DataInputStreamDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      InputStream is = null;
      DataInputStream dis = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
      short[] s = {12982,3568};

      try{
         // create file output stream
         fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");

         // create data output stream
         dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

         // for each short in short buffer
         for(short j:s)
         {
            // write short to data output stream
            dos.writeShort(j);
         }

         // force data to the underlying file output stream
         dos.flush();

         // create file input stream
         is = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");

         // create new data input stream
         dis = new DataInputStream(is);

         // available stream to be read
         while(dis.available()>0)
         {
            // read two bytes from data input, return short
            short k = dis.readShort();

            // print short value
            System.out.print(k+" ");
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         // if any error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // releases all system resources from the streams
         if(is!=null)
            is.close();
         if(dis!=null)
            dis.close();
         if(fos!=null)
            fos.close();
         if(dos!=null)
            dos.close();
      }
   }
}
```

> Output: 12982 3568

---

skipBytes()

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class DataInputStreamDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      InputStream is = null;
      DataInputStream dis = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
      byte[] b = {4,124,119,114,125,45,76,83,84};

      try{
         // create file output stream
         fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");

         // create data output stream
         dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

         // for each byte in buffer
         for(byte j:b)
         {
            // write byte to the output stream
            dos.writeByte(j);
         }

         // force data to the underlying file output stream
         dos.flush();

         // create file input stream
         is = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");

         // create new data input stream
         dis = new DataInputStream(is);

         // available stream to be read
         while(dis.available()>0)
         {
            // reads characters encoded with modified UTF-8
            int k = dis.read();

            // print
            System.out.print(k+" ");

            // skips 1 by
            dis.skipBytes(1);
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         // if any error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // releases all system resources from the streams
         if(is!=null)
            is.close();
         if(dis!=null)
            dis.close();
         if(fos!=null)
            fos.close();
         if(dos!=null)
            dos.close();
      }
   }
}
```

> Output: 4 119 125 76 84

Answer (score 2):

if you want to skip some bytes you can use 
1.readByte() method of DataInputStream and create a for loop of n size to skip n bytes and after that 
2.call readShort() method to read short values from the input stream
3.after that again call readByte() to skip again bytes.

feel free to ask your queries